# Losing characters in strings after performing a split with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to split a string into 2 strings,

my string looks like: 
HAMAN****3 whitespaces****409991

I want to have two strings the first with 'HAMAN' and the second should contain '409991'

**PROBLEM:** My second string has **'09991'** instead of **'409991'** after implementing this code:

```
        string str = "HAMAN   409991     ";
        string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\s4");
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
        }
```

**CURRENT SOLUTION with PROBLEM:**

Split my original string when I find whitespace followed by the number 4. The character '4' is missing in the second string.

**PREFERED SOLUTION:**

To split when I find 3 whitespaces followed by the digit 4. And have '4' mentioned in my second string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\s{3,}(?=4)");
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/jxWKFN)

Comment: @BadaBoom I've modified my answer, use this. earlier I overlooked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Positive lookahead is your friend:

```
Regex.Split(str, @"\s+(?=4)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could not use Regex:

```
var str = "HAMAN   409991     ";

var result = str.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

### [EXAMPLE](http://ideone.com/aElNqt)

---

Alternative if you need it to start with `SPACESPACESPACE4`:

```
var str = new[] { 
    "HAMAN   409991     ",
    "HAMAN  409991",
    "HAMAN   509991"
};

foreach (var s in str)
{
    var result = s.Trim()
                  .Split(new[] {"   "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(a => a.Trim())
                  .ToList();

    if (result.Count != 2 || !result[1].StartsWith("4"))
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", result[0], result[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm performing it with RegEx

Comment: There is a criteria "three white space followed by '4'". I think you missed that

Comment: @BadaBoom But do you _need_ to use regex?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're splitting including the 4. If you want to split by three-consecutive-spaces then you should specify exactly that:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\s{3}");
```

Comment: I need to split when 3 whitespaces are followed by a 4